# Randomly Sample Panel Data by Users in a manner Agnostic to User Key

Tags: python, random, bigdata

**Summary:**

How do I perform random sampling at the group level from a large panel dataset without loading to memory?

> Note that because I do not load to memory, I do not want to
>   validate the `id` key. I am also not necessarily certain of the format of the id. Is random sampling possible under these conditions?

Note: I use python-3.x.

**Detail:**

I have a large dataframe/csv file (>20GB) which is impractical to fit in memory. The structure of the data is a *panel*, which means it consists of groups of observations with the same `id`. For example, there are 20 million people with 100 observations each.

I want to sample ***at the user level***, which means for any sample, it should include all the observations for each user.

**Ideas:**

1. Make a hash of the `id` in a way that is agnostic to the format of the `id` (within reason). For example, the id could be the list of users by number or some alphanumeric sequence.
2. I would then filter this hash with a `filter` function that accepts a % of them.
3. Then run the `filter` across each observation, building a dataframe.

The problem is that I'm not confident about steps 1 or 2. I'm not sure how to create a hash that is random for all reasonable statistical purposes.

I'm sure this is a solved problem. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

There are a **lot** of ways to go about this. One of the most straightforward is using the `random` module to generate random numbers without repetition. Then you can use these numbers to pull the rows (people) corresponding to these numbers:

```
import random

random_list = random.sample(range(20000000), 100)
# From your 20 million people, grab the indices for 100 of them.

random_people = []

with open(file.txt) as f:
    idx = 0
    for line in f:
        if idx in random_list:  # Check if the person matches one of the random ones.
            random_people.append(line.strip())
```

Of course, you can adjust the numbers to your actual number of rows, number of people you want in the sample, etc.

Comment: Hi Jared,

A random sample is a good idea but this wouldn't work if the ids were alphanumeric characters or if I couldn't be certain that all ids had the same format.

Comment: Why not? This will pull random rows from your dataframe. Since you don't give an example, I assumed that's how your observations are set up (an ``id`` (or user) for each row followed by observations). Is that not the case? This doesn't care about the format of your ids, nor what they are. Give examples of what you have and what you want if you'd like more specific answers.